# Python Textfile - Assign Numbers to words in dic

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a txt file I'm pulling from sec.gov with the following code

```
import requests

cik = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt').text
mylist = cik.split()
```

output from the site looks like this:

```
aapl    320193
msft    789019
amzn    1018724
goog    1652044
fb      1326801
tcehy   1293451
```

And I splitted to have each ticker & number seperated as string like this:
`['aapl', '320193', 'msft', '789019', 'amzn', '1018724', 'goog', '1652044', 'fb', '1326801']`

How can I combine each Ticker with the following number?

Comment: Hint: `d[key] = value` will add an entry to a dictionary `d`. Do this in a loop that reads each line and splits it into a key and value.

Comment: @Likonima Welcome to SO. You mention that you tried something. Where is the trying I cannot see your python code still?

Comment: @Likonima, okay I think I put a step by step process which is helpful

Comment: Could you please add tab to `fb  1326801` since there is consistency in tabs and I could not edit it since edit needs atleast 6 characters or more I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to map the provided output to a dictionary through parsing is as follows:

Get the text output into response:

```
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt").text
```

Now, if you check the first line you will see that it is `aap1\t320193\n`. This is useful information that helps in understanding that a split by `\n` first then by `\t` can be performed and then append directly to a dictionary:

```
>>> combinations = resp.split("\n")
>>> dict_test = {}
>>> for element in combinations:
# Here, element.split("\t")[0] will be aap1 and element.split("\t")[1] will be 320193
    dict_test[element.split("\t")[0]] = element.split("\t")[1]
```

Finally, the first 5 output is shown below since the dictionary itself is too big:

```
>>> for idx, key in enumerate(dict_test.keys()):
    if idx == 5:
        break
    print("Key: {} and its Value: {}".format(key, dict_test[key]))
```

Output:

```
Key: aapl and its Value: 320193
Key: msft and its Value: 789019
Key: amzn and its Value: 1018724
Key: goog and its Value: 1652044
Key: fb and its Value: 1326801
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time. It did anser my question understandable. I also tried to split by \n but was wondering for the \t output.

Comment: If you think this has answered your question, you could upvote it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose that your list looks like this:

```
mylist = ["aapl    320193", "msft    789019", ...] # so on and so forth
mylist = [x.split() for x in mylist] # remove those excessive spaces
text = [x[0] for x in mylist] # grab the text
numbers = [x[1] for x in mylist] # grab the numbers
output_dict = dict(zip(text, numbers)) # magic!

>>> output_dict
{'aapl': '320193', 'msft': '789019', ...}
```

If you have one list of stocks and another of numbers, you can skip right to the `output_dict` step.

Comment: Why not just `dict(mylist)` after splitting? You're putting them into separate lists, then putting them back together with `zip()`.

Comment: It is actually not a real list. Instead it is a txt file I'm pulling from https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're asking how to map 2 lists to a dictionary, with the number as the key. This is how to do that:

```
word_lst = ["aapl", "msft", "amzn"]
num_list = [320193, 789019, 1018724] 
dic = {}

for i, item in enumerate(word_lst):
    dic[num_list[i]] = item
```

Comment: It is actually a website i call with requests & .text method in the same format i provided. For reference: https://www.sec.gov/include/ticker.txt